# What is the difference between a markdown server and web server?

Tags: tomcat, webserver, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have been using GitHub markdown files (.md) which I was able to run fine on Apache Tomcat, after giving up on trying to install the Allmark markdown server.

Since markdowns work fine on the Apache web server, I now wonder what the difference between the 2 (web server vs markdown server) really are? Is a web server simply a superset?

Comment: A "Markdown server" isn't really a thing. What do you mean when you say that Markdown files "work fine"? Are you just rendering them as HTML? What software are you using to do that?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Allmark](https://allmark.io/) website (which I had never heard of until this question):

> allmark is a file-system-centric markdown web server. You can point it at any directory that contains markdown files and it will immediately start a web-server that serves the rendered HTML content of the markdown file to you.

In other words, the "markdown web server" is simply a static file server with one additional feature: it converts Markdown files to HTML before serving them. Traditionally, web servers would only serve the Markdown files in their native Markdown format without converting them to HTML.

In fact, the default behavior of a basic Apache installation would simply serve the Markdown files as Markdown files (with no conversion). However, some individuals have created non-standard add-ons which do a conversion to HTML on-the-fly (such as [apache-mod-markdown](https://github.com/hamano/apache-mod-markdown), which I know nothing about except that it came up as the first search result for `Apache markdown`).

A more typical method of serving a collection of Markdown documents might be to run them through a [static site generator](https://github.com/hamano/apache-mod-markdown), which is a tool separate from the server that converts the Markdown files to HTML files. The HTML files are then copied to the server's file directory and served up without modification by the server.